# Unable to get access to specific directory to run a site on ec2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-permissions

Still fairly new to ec2, I made a new directory as /home/user/www. Opened ftp service that allows git commits to be pushed to the server. This works fine as I can see the files come up. The problem being when I run my site, the Apache test page pops up and when I try opening a page in /home/user/www directory, it says Forbidden, you don't have permission to access / on this server. 
I have successfully changed the DocumentRoot

```
DocumentRoot "/home/user/www"
AllowOverride None
# Allow open access:
Require all granted
```

and Directory in httpd.config to /home/user/www, all but to no result.
Any help is appreciated. Permissions are 777 for test basis but still no success. User is the owner of all the files in www

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question. Permissions need to be set on the third directory i.e., www. Therefore, I did chmod 755 ~/www. 
Worked like a charm